# Python : Scraping Websites Not Returning any Html

Tags: python, html, xpath, screen-scraping, analysis

So i'm having a problem grabbing a pages html for some reason when i send a request to the site then use `html.fromstring(site.content)` it grabs some pages html but then again some of them just print out `<Element html at 0x7f6359db3368>` 
Is there a reason for this? something i can do to fix this? is it some type of security? Also i don't want to use things like Beautiful Soup or Scapy yet.. I Want to learn some more before i decide to get into those libraries...

Comment: what website are you scrapping? what does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: what you're getting are HTML Element objects. If you want to get its contents try appending `.text` at the end

Comment: Use `print(site.content)` to get HTML as text. `html.fromstring(..)` converts HTML to objects and `<Element html at 0x7f6359db3368>` inform you that you have object. And now you can use its methods to easily search subobjects, arguments, text, etc. Read documentation how to work with `Element`.

Comment: At first i was using the html fromstring so i can get the xpath of objects , what im trying to do is get a sites content and find a text on a button that takes you to the last page of the site and i want it to set a variable as that number and use a while condition to visit each page and scrape off the names of each game on the site..

Comment: But printing the content helped that worked now i need to figure out when i try to print an xpath it just gives me a blank array? or sometimes just a bunch of '/n' symbols

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help a little:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

a = requests.get('https://www.python.org/')
b = html.fromstring(a.content)
d = b.xpath('.//*[@id="documentation"]/a')    #XPath to the blue 'Documentation' near the top of the screen 
print(d)         #prints [<Element a at 0x104f7f318>]
print(d[0].text) #prints Documentation
```

You can usually find the XPath with the Chrome Developer tools, after viewing HTML. I'd be happy to give more specific help if you wanted to post the website you're scrapping, and what you're looking for.

Comment: Im Doing 3 of them for now then adding the other ones in later when i learn more on how to do this

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand. It would be much clearer with your (simplified) code, what you're currently getting as your result, and what expect your result to be.

Comment: Just to be clear, all you want is the number of pages?

Comment: Yes the number of Max pages which is like a little over 600 but i want it to grab it so when there page updates it wont break my tool